# Discrete math proof dealing with injective function

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Assume, that $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is injective and that $A,B ⊂ X$. Show, that $f[A \cap B] = f[A] \cap f[B].$

How would on sketch out a relatively rigorous proof from this?

Comment: Have you tried anything? How do you usually prove that 2 sets are equal?

Comment: By proving that both are subsets of each other, however this one got really messy and I just couldn't get it to work...

Comment: How would you start the proof of $f(A\cap B)\subseteq f(A)\cap f(B)$? This is true for any function $f$, you don't need even need injectivity for this direction

Comment: Yeah the problem was actually the other direction. Let $y \in f(A ∩ B)$.

Then $\exists x \in X$ such that $f(x) = y$. etcetc, this is how i started the first direction and it went pretty ok.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

As mentioned in a comment, $f(A\cap B)\subset f(A)\cap f(B)$ is valid for any function $f$, for an obvious reason.

For the converse, suppose $x\in f(A)\cap f(B)$, i.e. $x$ can be written $f(a)$ as well as $f(b)$ for some $a\in A$ and $b\in B$. What can you say of $a$ and $b$?

Comment: The problem is that I don't know how to start the converse and prove it rigorously...

Comment: My first sentence is a starting point.